# Code continues to execute after return statement

Tags: java, algorithm, return

I wrote an algorithm that recursively calculates the sum of the square of the given number's digits, and if the sum ends up to be equal to 1, I would like it to return true.

I verified that I calculated correctly the sum, if the given number is 19, the next one is going to be 82, followed by 68, and finally 100 which should return true.
I checked whether the program goes inside the `if(sum==1)` and it does.
If I print the sum before `return false;`, it weirdly prints the resulting sum in descending order (1, 68, 82) before returning false.

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isHappy(int n) {
    int sum =0;
    int digit =0;
    while (n>0) {
        digit =n%10;
        sum=sum+digit*digit;
        n=n/10;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    if(sum==1){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        isHappy(sum);
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with my code? Why does it not stop after the sum is 1 and it has to return true?

Comment: You call `isHappy(sum);`, but you ignore what it returns (thus making that code completely useless).

Comment: `isHappy()` when called will either return `true` (if the sum of the square of digits happens to be 1) or `false` (otherwise). In the latter case, it will recursively call itself, but completely useless (besides the side-effect of `System.out.println`, which I take as debuging info only). I don't get your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not returning the return value of `isHappy(sum)` might be the issue. See if this works as expected:

```java
class Solution {
    public boolean isHappy(int n) {
        if (n == 0) return false;

        int digit, sum = 0;

        while (n > 0) {
            digit = n % 10;
            sum += digit * digit;
            n /= 10;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }

        if(sum == 1) return true;
        else return isHappy(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: lol okay, yes, it worked, thank you. I see that you put the recursive call in the ```else``` part but still don't really understand how I wrote the same thing for the ```if``` part and it didn't return true.

Comment: It basically returns the value from the else call, and at one point you're going to call the function with 0, in which case the base case (first line in the function) returns false. Your function was just missing the base case.

Comment: Your answer helped me in correcting the issue with my recursion for the last 3-4 hours. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You must return the value of your recursive call.

This will be your stack when you call `isHappy(19)`:

> - sum != 0. Call isHappy(82). **return false**
> - sum != 0. Call isHappy(68). **return false**
> - sum != 0. Call isHappy(100). **return false**
> - sum == 0. return true: **this doesn't mean your method will return true. The recursive call in the stack somewhere returned it, but it's not anticipated in your method. Instead, you just tell your method to `return false` after you make another call to `isHappy()`.**

To fix this, as tripathiakshit also mentioned, you need to **return the value of your recursive call**:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isHappy(int n) {
        int sum =0;
        int digit =0;
        while (n>0) {
            digit =n%10;
            sum=sum+digit*digit;
            n=n/10;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
        if(sum==1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return isHappy(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

I would also suggest taking some safety measures to prevent a stack overflow. You should check if there will be a case where your method will never find a happy sum. You can simply create a base case to prevent this:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isHappy(int n, int callCount) {
        if(callCount > 10) return false; // Stopping recursion if we exceed 10 calls
        int sum = 0;
        int digit = 0;
        while (n > 0) {
            digit = n % 10;
            sum = sum + digit * digit;
            n = n/10;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
        if(sum == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            callCount++;
            return isHappy(sum, callCount);
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can call `isHappy(19, 0);` with the comfort of being safe from exceptions and/or infinite loops.

Answer (score 0):

return false will be executed in the final call stack, as the value returned from isHappy(sum) is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

isHappy(100) does in fact return true. You can try it

However, isHappy(82) and isHappy(68) will return false because you never use the value from the recursive call. You just compute it and return false

```
    class Solution {
    public boolean isHappy(int n) {
    int sum =0;
    int digit =0;
    while (n>0) {
        digit =n%10;
        sum=sum+digit*digit;
        n=n/10;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    if(sum==1){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        isHappy(sum);  -- the recursive call's value is unused
    }
    return false;      -- you return false regardless of the computed value
    }
}
```

the only change you have to make for it to work as expected is:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isHappy(int n) {
    int sum =0;
    int digit =0;
    while (n>0) {
        digit =n%10;
        sum=sum+digit*digit;
        n=n/10;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
    if(sum==1){
        return true;
    }
    return isHappy(sum);  -- Here
    }
}
```